# MySQL - How to change the order of rows in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How to change the order of rows in order to have the rows ordered by custom_field?

For example I have got table with id asc and would like to have the rows in the desc order. I need it in order not to use the 'order by id desc' in the mysql query to optimize the query speed.

I tried:

```
insert table_with_ordered_rows() 
select * from table_with_not_ordered_rows order by id desc;
```

but it just copy the table with standard asc order.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get the sorted result set in mysql - is to add `ORDER BY` in query.

> in the mysql query to optimize the query speed.

It is incorrect. If you have issues with query performance - then ask about query performance. Give us complete table structure, the query, the explain and statistics about data.

Comment: Table is very simple but there is about million of rows in that table, so 'order by' is slowing down the query quite much.

Comment: @Newbie1: as I said - if you want to solve your task - you need to ask proper question about query issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER `tablename` ORDER BY `orderField` DESC;
```

But you must execute this query after each insert. See [13.1.7. `ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: This will work until one more row is added. Also - mysql is not required to return the data in this order if you use any `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to guarantee order in a result set is to use an `ORDER BY` clause.  An `ORDER BY` can make use of an index, if one exists...

That said, the following worked for me on MySQL 5.1.49:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

INSERT INTO t1 (col) VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c');
```

Result set:

```
id  col
--------
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Intermediate table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

INSERT INTO t2 (col, old_id)
  SELECT t.col, t.id
    FROM t1 t
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Result set:

```
id  col  old_id
----------------
1   c    3
2   b    2
3   a    1
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! You said that "The only way to guarantee order in a result set is to use an ORDER BY clause", but ORDER BY slow down the query even when there is decent optimization and indexes, so the default order by inserts could fix it or you have better idea?

Comment: But that is not really the goal I would like to achieve as I would like to have the id assigned to rows like in old table and just change the order of rows (like order of inserts).